# Consider the convergence of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the convergence of the sequence $a_1 =1, a_{n+1} = a_n + {{a_n^2}\over{n(n+1)}}$

I use $a_{n+1}-a_n={{a_n^2}\over{n(n+1)}}$ or $a_{n+1}=a_1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k^2}{k(k+1)}$ and I don't have idea anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Claim.** For $n\ge 25$, $|a_n| \le 5-25/n$.

*Proof.* For $n=25$, You can check it by direct calculation. ($a_{25} \approx 3.80588$) If it holds for $n$, then

$$|a_{n+1}| \le |a_n| + \frac{|a_n|^2}{n(n+1)}\le 5-\frac{25}{n} + \frac{25}{n(n+1)} = 5-\frac{25}{n+1}$$

By the claim, $\langle a_n\rangle$ is bounded. Moreover, $\langle a_n\rangle$ is increasing so it converges by monotone convergence theorem.